# Returning value on null linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Hi I have following linq query

```
var query=DbContext.Set<tasksList>()
Select(u=> new { tasks= u.description});
```

What I want to do is as it iterates through if description is null to return some other value for example return just 1 or anything. 
Please let me know how to achieve this Thanks

Comment: var query=DbContext.Set<tasksList>()
Select(u=> new { tasks= u.description ?? "just 1 or anything"});

Comment: @Biscuits why don't you write your comment as an answer? It seems correct to me.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the null coalescing operator.

```
var query = DbContext.Set<tasksList>()
                  .Select(u=> new { tasks= u.description ?? "just 1 or anything"});
```

*Example*:
[Code Project - How to Use Null-Coalescing Operator (??)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/644347/How-to-Use-Null-Coalescing-Operator)

*Reference*:
[Reference MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: It works partially if description is null. When the record is null it doesnt work. So if query =null I want to assign description some value as well so query always have some number when it returns

Comment: I don't see how query would equal null. Do you mean when the result set is empty (zero rows)?

Comment: Yes. When row is empty it just return query=[] , In this case I want to get at least one value in it so i can assign it on my view. Thanks

Comment: It's going to be quite tough to work that out without seeing how you're returning the results to the view. Maybe update your question and also ask about making up a single row when the results are empty.